# Start timers in Java

Tags: java, timer

I want a particular piece code to be executed after 5 minutes. How can I do that using Java?

```
        out.println("<HTML>");
        out.println("<head>");
        //out.println("<frame>");
        out.println("<frameset rows=\"80%, *\" frameborder=\"0\" border=\"0\" framespacing=\"0\">");
       out.println("<frame src=\"DataCenterImage.html\" target=\"DisplayFrame\">"); 
       //out.println("Hai");
        out.println("<frame src= \"unlock.html\" target=\"DisplayFrame\">"); 
        out.println("</frameset>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("</HTML>");
```

I want the above to be excuted after 15 minutes.

Comment: Are you trying to send some data to a client in a Servlet after 5/15 minutes? In this case all the (otherwise correct) answers below won't help you. Please ask about your problem, not what you think the solution is.

Comment: I think the edit by starblue made the problem more unclear. Why did he (starblue) add all that stuff about printing HTML, which wasn't in the original question?

Answer (score 3):

In Java 1.5 and above you can use the `java.util.concurrent` package

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadedScheduledExecutor();
ScheduledFuture<?> f = scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //Code to be executed here
    }
}, 15L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

You can cancel the execution thus:

```
f.cancel(false);
```

Comment: Your question says "5 minutes". If it's 15 I'll edit the code

Comment: I agree that Quartz is overkill. That is why I voted +1 on your answer. I still gave my answer for completeness

Answer (score 1):

The [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) framework may also be helpful to you.

From their site:

> Quartz is a full-featured, open source job scheduling system that can be integrated with, or used along side virtually any J2EE or J2SE application - from the smallest stand-alone application to the largest e-commerce system. Quartz can be used to create simple or complex schedules for executing tens, hundreds, or even tens-of-thousands of jobs; jobs whose tasks are defined as standard Java components or EJBs. The Quartz Scheduler includes many enterprise-class features, such as JTA transactions and clustering.

I have used this a lot for scheduling in different type of applications and have been very happy with it.

Comment: Using Quartz is a bit heavy-handed for the answer to "I want to execute X in 5 minutes". I would only consider Quartz if I wanted cron-like execution, missed triggers, stateful execution etc etc

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
Thread.sleep(900000);
execute code...
```

The sleep() method takes milliseconds as arguments, therefore the huge number for your 15 minutes.

Comment: u mean i need to have a class that extends httpservlet and implements runnable thread

Comment: No, with Thread.sleep you tell the current thread to wait for a given amount of time. You don't need to implement anything.